# paraphrasing of would have p.p

Tags: phrase-meaning, auxiliary-verbs, paraphrasing

"*I can't think why he would have accused me in court yesterday.*"

Can this sentence be paraphrased to "*It's possible that he accused me in court yesterday, but, if he did, I don't know why.*"?